# Removing white space in Mustache/Handlebars files

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

I have a large Mustache file similar to the following after it is minified.

An example:

`<div>{{#typeSettings.showCaret}}    <span>My span</span>{{/typeSettings.showCaret}}</div>`

I am trying to find a JavaScript solution to remove extraneous white space that would not affect the structure of the template. It isn't as simple as adding a regex to replace spaces because some of the white space is necessary. In my example the space in `My span` is needed while the spaces preceding the opening span tag are not.

Does anyone know of an existing solution to remove such white space in a Mustache or Handlebars file or is this something I will need to write my own regex to do?

Comment: So basically remove any whitespace that isn't between `><`?

Comment: @webnoob sort of, but it isn't quite that straight forward. For tags like `<span class="my-class">My span</span>` the spaces within the tags themselves would also need to be preserved.

Comment: Is the whitespace only after the mustache tags?

Comment: @webnoob no not necessarily. There are also instances of things like ```<div>    <span>My span</span>   </div>``` where the white space would need to be removed between tags. Thanks for taking the time to consider this.

Comment: Ok, well in that case, my thought is to loop through the content checking for `> ` or `} ` and replacing with `>` and `}` respectively until no instances are found. This should remove one space at a time until all gone. Are there other instances that would stop that from working?

Comment: @webnoob That's a good idea and I'll see how far that gets me. If it turns out that the majority of the white space is around either a `>` or `}` I'll probably end up doing it with a regex after all since the number of spaces fluctuates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a problem, good luck!